# Using an IDE on Windows (IDLE) but running code on Pi Raspbian Stretch

Tags: python, windows, python-idle

I'm trying to re-educate myself on object-oriented programming usng Python.  I'm an old time programmer with roots in Fortran and Cobol.  Currently I'm writing Python code on my Windows 10 Pro laptop using IDLE and then transferring the code to a Raspberry Pi to run.

So my question:  I've installed some systems, like pyModbus, onto the Pi from the GIT site.  The code generally works on the Pi, but on the laptop when coding I get no help/feedback on the available objects and their properties/methods.  I've done some macros programming for MS Excel and I like the VBA editor there as it does show the objects, etc.

For this type for code development, what do I have to do to have something like the VBA editor?  A different IDE?  How do I get the objects which I have installed on the Pi (Raspbian Stretch) also available to an IDE on my laptop?

Thanks for any help/advice....RDK

Comment: This question kind of falls in the category of "what's your favorite python IDE?" which really depends on your personal preferences. I suggest you just search for
"python ide windows"
and try out a few options.

Comment: A key part of my question has to do with writing code on a Windows platform, but running it on a Linux platform.  How do I synchronize the objects on the Linux box to the Windows box so that object properties and methods will be recognized by the Windows IDE

Comment: pymodbus implements the modbus protocol, which I assume does not exist on a Windows laptop.  Does 'import pymodbus' even work? Even if it did, you would need a modbus emulator to run the resulting code on your laptop.\

Comment: I'll look into this, however, I only write the code on the laptop, it runs on a Pi.  My question is really more generic than just for pyModbus.  I need to know how to develop/code on my laptop for programs I will run on the Pi